# Simple.Data InMemoryAdapter - FindAllByX(IEnumerable<string>)

Tags: c#, simple.data

Like the title says, is it some way to make this statemant work (using InMemoryAdapter):

```
Database.Open().MySchema.MyTextResource.FindAllByX((IEnumerable<string>)myVariable);
```

IT returns 0 rows now, but if i do

```
Database.Open().MySchema.MyTextResource.FindAllByX(((IEnumerable<string>)myVariable).First());
```

It return 1, so it matches the data, its the IEnumerable part that messes up.

Comment: Downvote, care to explain why?

Comment: Possibly because a lot more information are required to give a good answer.

Comment: Exactly what are you trying to achieve? I'm guessing that you are trying to return any values of X that match any of the values in the IEnumerable? Is that right? Or are you doing something else?

Comment: SQL equaliant WHERE X IN (Y, Z, Å, Ä, Ö). It works against the sql provider, but not the InMemoryAdapter.